# Setting up Remote access home LAN behind multiple routers?

Tags: router, lan, remote-access

I split/share an internet connection with family members that live next door to my house. I don't have/need/want cable, so they have the modem. I have admin/config access to all components involved.

I have a NAS server on my end that I cannot figure out how to access from outside my LAN. My network components are arranged thusly:

```
Internet
|
|
V
[next door]
|
|
V
ISP Cable Modem
|
V
Router: D-Link DI-524
|
|
[my house]
|
|
V
Access Point: UBNT Nanostation (necessary for reliably strong WiFi signal from next door)
|
V
Router: Engenius ESR1221 (EXT)
|
V
NAS: Synology ds210j
```

It took me forever just to configure an internet connection to my house through all of those components, I'm maxing out my knowledge-level here.

I've worked on accessing the NAS, off & on, for months with no luck. I've tried accessing different components (file server, ftp, VPN server, etc.), with SSL / without SSL, I've forwarded ports, DMZ'd inner router, DMZ'd the NAS, setup a dynDNS account. All in such a disorderly fashion that some combination thereof may be the answer & I danced around it.

At any rate, I'm looking for an explanation of the networking concepts to do this (if one exists) that ignores what I've tried so far & focuses on the components involved.

Comment: Check what port you need to configure to allow the NAS to be connected to from outside your lan.  It may not be possible with that NAS.  The ISP can also be blocking the ports necessary to make this work. Figure out what port to forward and then see if it is blocked by your ISP.

Comment: What mode is the UBNT Nanostation set up in?  Are the two networks set up on different IP Address ranges?

Answer (score 3):

Add Static Routing on each of your routers both ways so that all traffic from your LAN IP goes thru up and down to/from the final router